# RDCOMClient Outlook Add Reminder in R

Tags: r, outlook

I am using this function in R to sending emails, however, I would like to add also "Add Reminder" to the emails in order to remind the action recipients later on. Is it possible?

Thank you

```
library(RDCOMClient)
mail_fun <- function(email, name, number) {
  Outlook <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  Email = Outlook$CreateItem(0)
  # Email parameters
  #Email[["sentonbehalfofname"]] = ""
  Email[["to"]] = email
  Email[["cc"]] = ""
  Email[["bcc"]] = ""
  Email[["importance"]] = "2"
  Email[["readreceiptrequested"]] = FALSE
  Email[["originatordeliveryreportrequested"]] = FALSE
  Email[["subject"]] = paste0("Confirm your Telia SIM card delivery with the phone number: ", number)
  Email[["Body"]] = paste0("Dear ", name,",", "\n", "\n", "I would like to ask you for a confirmation that a new Telia SIM card with the phone number: ", number, " was delivered to you.", 
                           " Your confirmation is very important for a successful porting from H3Gi to Telia. The porting is planned for September 14th 2021.", "\n",
                           "In case you have not received the SIM card yet, please let us know your delivery address and we will send you a new SIM card.",
                           "\n", "\n", "Thank you for your cooperation.", "\n", "\n", "Best regards,", "\n", "Jaroslav Kotrba")
  # Email send
  Email$Send()
}

# Send
mapply(mail_fun, DK$email, DK$name, DK$number)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in setting up the [MailItem.FlagRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.flagrequest) property which returns or sets a string that indicates the requested action for a mail item. By default, a mail item is not marked with any flag and the default value for this property is the empty string.

```
Email[["flagrequest"]] = "Reply"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really cool, do you perhaps know also how to set the reminder e.g. 4 hours later?

Comment: See [How to send Outlook Emails with attached Flag and Reminder in VBA](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=vba-outlook-email-flag-task-reminder)

Comment: I am trying something like this: FlagDueBy = DateAdd("d", 2, Date) in R, but it does not work, getting an error. Do you know how to set it in R. It would be really helpful, I tried Email[["flagdueby"]] = as.Date(Sys.Date()) + 1

Comment: That's another question, I'd suggest posting this in a separate thread.